# C# could not resolve the symbol refers to existing property while nullable check has been executed

Tags: c#, blazor

C# tells me:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'InvokeAsync'

at `await this.onClick.InvokeAsync(this.targetPerson);` line of below code:

```cs
public partial class PersonCard : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase
{

  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Parameter] 
  public required CommonSolution.Entities.Person targetPerson { get; set; }

  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Parameter]
  public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<CommonSolution.Entities.Person>? onClick { get; set; } = null;

  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Parameter] 
  public string rootElementTag { get; set; } = "div";

  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Parameter]
  public string? spaceSeparatedAdditionalCSS_Classes { get; set; } = null;
  
  
  private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task onClickOutermostElement()
  {

    if (this.onClick is null)
    {
      return;
    }
    
    
    await this.onClick.InvokeAsync(this.targetPerson);
    
  }

}
```

If make `onClick` non-nullable and remove null check, the compiling will work.
What wrong I am doing?

Comment: Check , this works
if (this.onClick != null)
{
    await this.onClick.InvokeAsync(this.targetPerson);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `EventCallback` is a `readonly struct`: a value type which in C# can't be null.

You can make it a nullable type, but there's no point in a parameter.  You switch between a nullable type and normal type in your code, which the compiler doesn't like.

If you want to check if a delegate has been assigned to the parameter you can check the `HasDelegate` property.

Here's an example where I rather drastically throw an exception if it has no delegate.

```cs
<h3>CallbackComponent</h3>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OnValueChanged">Get TimeStamp</button>

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task OnValueChanged()
    {
        if (!this.ValueChanged.HasDelegate)
            throw new Exception("Value changed must be assigned a delegate!");

        await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync($"Changed At {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike regular C# events, EventCallback can’t be null (since it’s a struct).
If you want to check the event i recommend this post.
[Check if EventCallback has been set Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59903182/check-if-eventcallback-has-been-set-blazor)

However your code won't compile since `onclick` is of type

```
EventCallback<CommonSolution.Entities.Person>?
```

What you propably mean is

```
EventCallback<CommonSolution.Entities.Person?>
```

Then the code would compile.